# Serial Communication Arduino C++ Builder

Tags: arduino, builder, vcl

I am trying to write an Application with C++ Builder which should display for example the temperature and humidity of a measurement from the Arduino. Arduino and my Application are connected via TComPort. I am using a Baudrate of 115200.

VCL Code:

```
AnsiString temp, hum;

ComPort1->ReadStr(temp, 5);
RichEdit1->Text = temp;

ComPort1->ReadStr(hum, 5);
RichEdit3->Text = hum;
```

Arduino Code:

```
DHT dht(10, DHT11);

void setup(void)
{
dht.begin();
Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop(void)
{
// Measure the humidity & temperature
float h = dht.readHumidity();
float t = dht.readTemperature();

// Transform to String
String temp = String( t );
String hum =  String( h );
delay(10);
Serial.print(temp);
Serial.print(hum); 

delay(5000);

}
```

When I start my Application (VCL with C++ Builder) and connect to the Arduino every 5 seconds, the values should be refreshed by new values. Most of the time the 2 values are correct and it displays like it should for example
Temperature: 24:00
Humidity: 55.00
But for some reason every now and then it displays something like this:
Temperature: .0051
Humditiy: .00

or some other weird values. 5 seconds later the values are correct again. This happens every 20-30 seconds 1 time and i dont know why this keeps happening.

Comment: Looks like you are occasionally catching it in the middle of a transmission.  When you see the weird ones, are the ones right before or after them right?  OR do the messed up ones seem to come in pairs?

Comment: And why are you converting the temp and humidity values to String before you print them?  You know the Print class can handle floats all by itself.  The String class is a memory waster and a memory fragmenter that shouldn't be used on any serious microcontroller project.

Comment: Hey many thanks for yout comment, first thanks i didnz know that with the strings class :) i will change that, second normally the first ones are right values then both values in pair get so weird and the next ones are alright again so like in between they are weird. There are little few times were there were 2 weird ones in a row.

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be any issue in the sending code.  The problem almost has to be on the receiving side.

Comment: I noticed that when i set the baudrate to 9600 i am not getting any good values, after setting it to 115200 there are only few weird ones left but thats all i figured out so far

Comment: That just speaks even more to an issue on the receiving end giving up and printing the result before it has been completely sent.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure i only get „complete results“? Or did i miss any code to complete the one above?

Comment: The problem isn't with the Arduino code.  Once more, the issue is with the code that is reading from the Arduino.  The Arduino is sending the complete thing.  The receiver isn't waiting for all of it to get there.  So the problem is NOT with the Arduino code.

Comment: Yeah i got that :D but i dont really know how to adjust my code for the application to get the code to work properly

Comment: I only see a few lines of it so I'm not sure what you want me to do.  It's written in another language.  Maybe the Arduino section isn't the best place to get help with the VCL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `TComPort.OnRxChar` event, there is a `Count` parameter that tells you how many bytes are available.  Don't read more than that.  Buffer the bytes to the side, and then read only complete values from that buffer.

For example:

```
private:
    AnsiString ComPortBuffer;

void __fastcall TMyForm::ComPort1RXChar(TObject *Sender, int Count)
{
    AnsiString s;

    int len = ComPort1->ReadStr(s, 5);
    if (len > 0)
    {
        if (len < 5)
            s.SetLength(len);
        ComPortBuffer += s;
    }

    while (ComPortBuffer.Length() >= 10)
    {
        AnsiString temp = ComPortBuffer.SubString(1, 5);
        AnsiString hum  = ComPortBuffer.SubString(6, 5);
        ComPortBuffer.Delete(1, 10);

        // use temp and hum as needed...
        RichEdit1->Text = temp;
        RichEdit3->Text = hum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, will try this one :)

Comment: i just wonder the part "int len = ComPort1->ReadStr(s, 5);" .... the variable "len" will always be the number i put in the brackets in ReadStr or not? So why do i have to say if( len < 5), will this ever happen ?